# ошибка при поиске в массиве Kotlin

Tags: java, массивы, kotlin

есть код:

```
Spark.get("nextUser"){r,_ ->
    val roomid = r.queryParams("roomid").toInt()
    val room = rooms.find { it.roomid == roomid }!!
    val activeUser = room.users.find { it.userid == room.activeUserID }!!
    var nextUserIndex = room.users.indexOf(activeUser) + 1
    if (nextUserIndex > room.users.size){
        nextUserIndex = 0
    }
    room.activeUserID = room.users[nextUserIndex].userid
}
```

крашится на этой строке, не могу понять почему:

```
val activeUser = room.users.find { it.userid == room.activeUserID }!!
```

Comment: В сообщении об ошибке написано почему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не приложили код ошибки. Но думаю, что там банальный `NullPointerException`.

Почему так происходит? Потому что функция find возвращает nulluble результат, т.е. она может не найти элемент, удовлетворяющий предикат и вернуть **null**.

В вашем случае `rooms.find { it.roomid == roomid }` может не иметь объекта с нужным вам id.

Вы используете `!!` это является плохой практикой. Kotlin вам говорит, что переменная может быть null и вам стоило бы обработать ситуацию с **null**. Можете использовать стандартный способ Java с проверкой на **null** через `if` или использовать оператор ["Элвис"](https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/reference/null-safety.html) Котлина ?:.

Когда вы ставите `!!` вы явно говорите компилятору: "Я уверен, что тут не будет **null**", но функция find может вернуть null и по факту вы просто игнорируете потенциальную ошибку.

Comment: Спасибо. Я решил с помощью `?.let`